# Content overflowing the flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the dropdown flex to be like this

[image]

This is what I found on internet, it uses simple dropdown menu.

I want the dropdown menu using flexbox and its properties. The problem is that the number of elements in a column is dynamic but flexbox container do not change its height according to it.

This is what I get

[image]

The code

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
nav ul {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li > ul.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}
li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.drop-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.drop-col > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.drop-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ff3546;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <script src="live.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">SoulOTrip</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="#">Adventure Trips</a>
                <ul class="drop-menu">
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Airforce</li>
                            <li>Flying fox</li>
                            <li>Bungee Jumping</li>
                            <li>Paragliding</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Army</li>
                            <li>Skiing</li>
                            <li>Mountaineering</li>
                            <li>Trekking</li>
                            <li>Rock Climbing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Navy</li>
                            <li>River Rafting</li>
                            <li>Parasailing</li>
                            <li>Scuba Diving</li>
                            <li>Swimming</li>
                            <li>Kayaking</li>
                            <li>Surfing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Username</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove height: 50px; from nav ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you accidently target the drop down menu as well and thus restrict it to `50px` as well. You can fix this, by changing the selector from

```
nav ul { 
   /* this affects all ul elements inside the nav, the first level
      .left as well as the .drop-menu */ 
}
```

to the following:

```
nav > ul { /* <- this affects only the direct descendant (ul.left) */ }
```

Alternatively you could change the `height` declaration to `min-height`.

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
nav > ul {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li > ul.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}
li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.drop-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.drop-col > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.drop-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ff3546;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <script src="live.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">SoulOTrip</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="#">Adventure Trips</a>
                <ul class="drop-menu">
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Airforce</li>
                            <li>Flying fox</li>
                            <li>Bungee Jumping</li>
                            <li>Paragliding</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Army</li>
                            <li>Skiing</li>
                            <li>Mountaineering</li>
                            <li>Trekking</li>
                            <li>Rock Climbing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Navy</li>
                            <li>River Rafting</li>
                            <li>Parasailing</li>
                            <li>Scuba Diving</li>
                            <li>Swimming</li>
                            <li>Kayaking</li>
                            <li>Surfing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Username</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: changing `nav ul` to `nav > ul` works as my need. Time to revise css selectors

Comment: Especially in those nested menu structures, it is very easy to accidently target wrong elements. That's why I either use the direct descendant selector `>` or directly use classes/id (which you could as well, since all your elements have nice class names already).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the end goal, you want to change `nav ul { height: 50px; }` to `min-height: 50px`

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
nav ul {
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li > ul.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}
li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.drop-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.drop-col > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.drop-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ff3546;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <script src="live.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">SoulOTrip</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="#">Adventure Trips</a>
                <ul class="drop-menu">
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Airforce</li>
                            <li>Flying fox</li>
                            <li>Bungee Jumping</li>
                            <li>Paragliding</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Army</li>
                            <li>Skiing</li>
                            <li>Mountaineering</li>
                            <li>Trekking</li>
                            <li>Rock Climbing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="drop-header">Navy</li>
                            <li>River Rafting</li>
                            <li>Parasailing</li>
                            <li>Scuba Diving</li>
                            <li>Swimming</li>
                            <li>Kayaking</li>
                            <li>Surfing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Username</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```